# how to populate radiobuttons in a form that being echoed as a string in php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a PHP script that receives data from jquery through ajax and then executes a query to retrieve the data back from MySql. After retrieving the data back, I would like to populate a bunch of radio buttons in a form with this data. The form is appended to a variable `$output` which will be sent back to the ajax as a string. How can I populate the radio buttons depending on the data? I tried the following but all it did is override the string with the following result "checked". Any help is appreciated.

```
<td class="answers"><input type="radio" name="quality_of_service" value="4" "%'.($result["quality_of_service"] === 3) ? 'checked':''.'%"></td>
```

My PHP

```
<?php
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id = $_POST['id'][0];

/*  print_r($id);*/
}
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//begin the transaction
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT quality_of_service, self_improvement, personal_behavior, organization_rules_commitment, team_work, appearance, work_with_high_responsibility, loyalty_to_organization, punctuality_on_work, office_maintaining, areas_of_improvement, points_of_weakness, points_of_strength FROM appraisals_table WHERE Apr_Id = :id");



$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($result)) {

$output .= '
<form id="reviewForm" action="" method="POST">

<div id="myRate">
How would you rank the employee in the following areas ?<span class="error">*</span><br>
<table class="myRateTable">
<tr id="table-header">
<th></th>
<th>Excellent<br><br>(4)</th>
<th>Above Average<br><br>(3)</th>
<th>Average<br><br>(2)</th>
<th>Poor<br><br>(1)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="questions">Quality of Service</td> 
<td class="answers"><input type="radio" name="quality_of_service" value="4" "%'.($result["quality_of_service"] === 3) ? 'checked':''.'%"></td>
<td class="answers"><input type="radio" name="quality_of_service" value="3"></td>
<td class="answers"><input type="radio" name="quality_of_service" value="2"></td>
<td class="answers"><input type="radio" name="quality_of_service" value="1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
';


echo $output;
}


}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Why do you use 2 percentage signs?

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you make it little simpler as,

```
if($result["quality_of_service"] === 3)
{
  <td class="answers">
      <input type="radio" name="quality_of_service" value="4" checked>
  </td>
}
else
{
    <td class="answers">
      <input type="radio" name="quality_of_service" value="4">
    </td>
}
```

Comment: That will be 40 if & else statements for my entire form. Also how can I add the if statement inside a string, I'm sure you can't.

Comment: NO, if you have 40 results in $result then you need to iterate on the result one by one and for each result you need to create a tr. So how there could be 40 if else? only one you need to add and the loop must do the rest logic

Comment: No, $result only have 10 results but I have 10 radiobuttons questions with 4 options for each.

Comment: You may have 100 results. Doesn't matter as you need to `loop` over each and hence above code will be added once in the loop.